# A Team of Five?

Tags: grammatical-number, terminology

If I am a team lead, and I lead 4 people in my team, do I say I am a "team lead of 4 people or 5?". You see, I am a *team member* too, and I have a specific role in addition to leading the team - so technically, the team has 5 people.

It's an entirely different story with a manager: as a manager, you manage subordinates who report to you. So you'd say: "4 people report to me" or "I manage 4 people".

So which one is more accurate?

Comment: I'm the leader of a 5-person team. I lead a team of five.

Comment: Mandatory: [Correct usage of “I lead a team of N specialists” in CVs / resumes](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/40974/44274)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is who established the team  / how it was formed :-

As  long as it is the organisation and not you , the team has been made of five people exactly with you being the leader.

If you have hired a group of four,  well then you lead exactly that — a team of four, irrespective of whether you consider yourself to be a part of it or not.

If five people have got together to form a team  on their own, well then you happen to be the leader of a five-  person team.

Comment: I really like the logic used here, very sound and reasonable.

Answer (score 6):

I would just say:

> I lead a five-person team.

At the end of the day, I don't think it makes a huge difference whether it's four or five members. *You* are a team leader; that's the point. (And I think most people would assume you're part of the team anyway.)

You could also say:

> I lead a five-person team, including myself.

But I think the first option is better.